# Why my v-for doesn't loop? VUE.JS with JSON

Tags: json, vue.js

I'm loading the data coming from a .json but the v-for does not return a loop.

MY HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <template v-for="product in products">
        <p>{{ product.brand }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.images }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.id }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.price }}</p>
    </template>

</div>
```

MY JS:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    products: []

},
methods: {

},
created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$http.get('http://localhost/app/products.json').then(function(response) {
        self.products = response.body;
    });
}
});
```

MY JSON:

```
"product": [
    {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "images":"images/iphone-x-64-gb.jpg",
        "id": "iphone-x-64-gb",
        "title": "iPhone X 64 GB",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "price": "1.159,00"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "images":"images/iphone-x-256-gb.jpg",
        "id": "iphone-x-256-gb",
        "title": "iPhone X 256 GB",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "price": "1.329,00"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "images":"images/iphone-8-64-gb.jpg",
        "id": "iphone-8-64-gb",
        "title": "iPhone 8 64 GB",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor.",
        "price": "819,99"
    }
   ]
  }
```

if I write in HTML like this dosen't work but if I put

{{ product[3].brand }}

for example ... I can see only this one, just loop dosen't working.

Answer (score 3):

Change your template to be something like the following...

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div  v-for="product in products">
              <p>{{ product.brand }}</p>
              <p>{{ product.images }}</p>
              <p>{{ product.id }}</p>
              <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
              <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
              <p>{{ product.price }}</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</template>
```

Vue templates require a single root element between the `<template>` tags and also I believe v-for won't work properly on root element so I am nesting that in a "wrapper."

If you look in your dev tools console you probably will see an error that says something like.

```
Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it 
renders multiple elements.
```

or

```
[Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. 
Render function should return a single root node.
```

---

### Additional

---

Also it appears you may have some other issues with your code. It seems to me your request should be like the following unless I am missing something about the way your json is being returned.

```
created: function() {
   this.$http.get('http://localhost/app/products.json').then(function(response) {
   this.products = response.body.products;
}.bind(this));
```

},

Notice the change from `response.body` to `response.body.products`  Also it is fine to assign `self` to `this` but I find  using `.bind(this)` more succinct.

Here is a working fiddle based on your code.  https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/umx98rxm/

Comment: You can also put another element inside the <template> tag working as root. I agree that using a div (span or whatever) instead of <template> is a better approach in this case though.

Comment: @Lucas G. What do you mean "..another element inside the <template> tag?"  You mean a second <template> tag inside the first?  You can use additional <template> or <slot> tags nested in the main <template> tag as throw away elements that wont get rendered, but they wont work as root element in my experience.  You have to use a div or span then the nested  template or slots.

Comment: Hi thank you for your effort, but this has not worked yet. I'm use Vue 2.5.13 and vue-resource v1.3.4 - https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource too, in inspect vue component I can see the <root> / data / products: Object / product: Array[3] / 0: Object / here the content of json normally. I think I got lost in the scopo.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer above.  Have a look at the working example here as well. https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/umx98rxm/   (note the myjson service I am using to load the json can be rather slow so just wait for it to load. )

Comment: If this was the answer to your issues, I would appreciate you marking the answer as accepted.